# Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String' for super.init

Tags: swift, oop

hey guys really simple question, new to the language. Not understanding what is wrong with the current code and why it gives the following error for this code. Tried everything, but not understanding.

```
class RPGCharacter
{
var maxHP: Int
var maxSP: Int
var currentHP: Int
var currentSP: Int
var type: String
var currentArmor: Armor
var currentWeapon: Weapon
var name: String
var bannedWeapon: [String]
var bannedArmor: [String]
init(nme: String)
{
    name = nme
    maxHP = 0
    maxSP = 0
    currentHP = 0
    currentSP = 0
    type = "undefined"
    currentArmor = NoArmor()
    currentWeapon = NoWeapon()
    bannedArmor = []
    bannedWeapon = []
}
// skipped some methods not relevant, plz ignore the missing bracket
class Fighter: RPGCharacter
{
 override init(nme: String)
{   super.init(nme: String) //error line Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String'
    maxHP = 40
    maxSP = 0
    currentHP = 40
    currentSP = 0
    type = "fighter"
    currentArmor = NoArmor()
    currentWeapon = NoWeapon()
    name = nme
    bannedArmor = []
    bannedWeapon = []
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

change

```
super.init(nme: String)
```

to

```
super.init(nme: nme)
```

When you pass a paramater to the init call, you need to pass a value.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler gives you an error because you pass an `String.Type` instead of `String` argument. This is because your superclass method (`init(nme: String)`) has one argument named `nme` which a type of `String`. You can pass the `nme` value instead of passing its type in you super call `super.init(nme: nme)` if you want to.

If you need a detail explanation about how initialization works and how you override an init method in Swift please read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html